# Different Levels for Different Appendors

Tags: logback

I need to generate 2 logging files for a java app.  One is for system admins, where they only want to see anything that is INFO or higher.  They don't want to see the TRACE or DEBUG levels, which greatly increase the size of the log files.  But we also want to generate a log file that can be sent to an engineer if something goes wrong.  The engineer will want all the details.  This will include all levels: TRACE,DEBUG,INFO,WARN, and ERROR.  I thought it would be as simple as this:

```
<logger level="INFO" additivity="false" name="com.mycompany">
    <appender-ref ref="NOT_DETAILED_FILE" />
</logger>       

<logger level="TRACE" additivity="true" name="com.mycompany">
    <appender-ref ref="DETAILED_FILE" />
</logger>
```

But I'm not getting what I expected.  Messages for the TRACE level are going into the general file.  I've read about custom logback filters.  But is this really necessarily? This seems like a fairly trivial use-case.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.  Delete the second logger you define for the package "com.mycompany".  This doesn't make sense.  The trick is to add a filter to the appendor that is "not detailed".

```
<appender name="NOT_DETAILED_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>logs/not-detailed.log</file>
    <append>false</append>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date{HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{175} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <!-- filter out any messages lower than INFO, like DEBUG or TRACE -->
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>INFO</level>
    </filter>
</appender>

<appender name="DETAILED_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>logs/detailed.log</file>
    <append>false</append>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date{HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{175} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="com.mycompany" level="trace"/>

<root level="warn">
    <appender-ref ref="DETAILED_FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="NOT_DETAILED_FILE" />
</root>
```